# warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘uint8_t * {aka unsigned char *}

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I've been getting an issue that says:

`warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘uint8_t * {aka unsigned char *}`

and I am not sure why this is happening because I thought int and uint8_t were interchangeable.

Here is my code:

```
uint8_t** fileRead(char* file, int* pointer) {
    FILE* file = fopen(file, "r");
    int count = 0;
    pointer = &count;
    fscanf(file, "%d", &count); //this retrieves a single integer
    uint8_t** result = (uint8_t**) malloc(*pointer * sizeof(uint8_t*));
    while (file != NULL) {
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < *pointer; i++) {
            uint8_t* a = (uint8_t*) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
            uint8_t* b = (uint8_t*) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
            uint8_t* c = (uint8_t*) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
            fscanf(file, "%d", a);
            fscanf(file, "%d", b);
            fscanf(file, "%d", c);
            if (a == NULL || b == NULL || c == NULL) {
                uint8_t* npointer = NULL;
                fclose(file);
                free(result);
                return NULL;
            } else {
                result[i][0] = *a;
                result[i][1] = *b;
                result[i][2] = *c;
                free(a);
                free(b);
                free(c);
           }
        }
    }
    return result; 
}
```

and the errors are occuring at the following lines:

```
fscanf(file, "%d", a);
fscanf(file, "%d", b);
fscanf(file, "%d", c);
```

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: @UnholySheep well `char` is an integer type on which arithmetic does work... if you are coming from, say, a Java background this is not such a strange mistake to make. Similar if you assume it is an integer therefore `%d` should work (not properly understanding how integer types work in C is a fairly common rookie mistake)...

Comment: Not related to the problem, but why are you using `malloc()` for variables that are only used locally within the function? Just declare local variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought int and uint8_t were interchangeable.

They are not - `int` (signed or unsigned) must be *at least* 16 bits wide (it may be wider, but not narrower)<sup>1</sup>. `uint8_t`, as the name suggests, is 8 bits wide.

You need to use the format specifier `%hhu` to read a numeric value into a `uint8_t` or `unsigned char` object.

---

1. Strictly speaking, an `int` must be able to represent all values in *at least* the range `[-32767..32767]`. That requires at least 16 bits.  Some architectures (which I've never used) have "padding bits" that contribute to the word size, but aren't used to store a value.  So, for example, you could have a 9-bit machine with 18-bit words, but an implementation on that system could still choose to just use 16 bits to represent an `int` value - two of the bits simply aren't used.

Answer (score 3):

Use `"%hhu"` as the format specifier instead of `"%d"`.

Answer (score 1):

To read an integer into an `unsigned char` with `(f)scanf`, you need `"%hhu"`.

Answer (score 1):

When printing, you can get away with using `%d` as the format specifier because a `uint8_t` is **promted** to an `int` when passed to a variadic function like `printf`.  This promotion does not however occur for pointers, which is what `scanf` expects for most format specifiers.

The `%d` format specifier for `scanf` as you've seen expects an `int *`.  On most systems you're likely to come across, an `int` is 4 bytes.  So when `scanf` dereferences the pointer you give it for `%d` to write the value it will write 4 bytes.  This breaks if you pass in a `uint8_t *` since this type only occupies 1 byte.  By using `%d`, `scanf` will think you're passing the address of an `int` and write 4 bytes, which is 3 bytes past the end of the given variable.  Doing this invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To fix this, change the format specifier to `%hhu`, which expects a `unsigned char *`.